# Connecting to SQL Server from NUnit test cases

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, nunit, testcase

I'm unable to connect to SQL Server while running from NUnit test cases. My SQL Server connection code sits in a different library.

Error

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connection.

I tried everything possible I found on the internet, couldn't resolve it. Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Well, quite simply: you don't seem to have *any* connection string, or a wrong one. You need to define the *right* connection string in your test project's main config file (`app.config` in a console app, `web.config` in a web app)

Comment: connection string is properly set, I hardcoded it - seems not working. Data Source=.\test;Initial Catalog=test-database;Trusted_Connection=True

Comment: Where in your test cases are you doing the connection?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using connection strings in NUnit or testing ADO.NET in general. Post your code. Also make certain that there *is* a `TEST` instance running on the machine that runs the test, ie your machine or the build server

Comment: @Charlie- Inserting record into db for some use-case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos- Test instance running on my machine. Giving error while opening connection. SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\test;Initial Catalog=test-database;Trusted_Connection=True"); connection.Open();

Comment: Error message - "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: NUnit 2 or 3? If 3, does it work with the `--inprocess` command line option? If so, then it is likely the fact that the user profile is not loaded into the nunit agent process when the tests are run. Let me know and I will update with a full answer.

Comment: One other question. If you write a simple console application that attempts to open the connection using the same connection string, does it work?